# dismissViewControllerAnimated not being called on iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I have the following code where I am trying to show a PDF preview. It words perfectly on an iPad however when I am trying to do it on a iPhone it dosnt work.

```
QLPreviewController* preview = [[QLPreviewController alloc] init];
        preview.dataSource = self;
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
            [self presentViewController:preview animated:YES completion:nil];
        }];
```

The thread on the iPhone never makes it to this line

```
[self presentViewController:preview animated:YES completion:nil];
```

but works fine on ipad.. I am not sure what to even look at. Any help would be appreaciated.

Comment: Is the view controller only supported on ipads? Try making a blank sample project with that framework and try presenting just that to see if Iphone supports it

Comment: The thread never enters that code block so its got something to do with dismissViewControllerAnimated...

Answer (score 1):

To access the instances/variables (that are declared outside of the block) inside a block, you need to declare those instances/variables like this:
__block type identifier = initial value (optional) e.g, in your case use
__block QLPreviewController* preview = [[QLPreviewController alloc] init];

Comment: Hrmm. Unfortually the thread is still not entering the code block. for some reason self dismissViewControllerAnimated is not being satisfied in the iphone. I have no idea why.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
[self.presentingViewController presentViewController:preview animated:YES completion:nil];
```

instead of

```
[self presentViewController:preview animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: This dosnt work. The reason it dosnt work is because the main thread when running on an iPhone dose not enter the code block.

I have tested my original code by removing the code block but keeping presentViewController line of code and that will actually load the preview however because its not in the code block later when I try to run the same code again it crashes.

Thank you for suggesting a solution.. however its unfortunate it did not work.

Comment: If you remove [self dismiss....] from code block and put there just NSLog(@""); and set breakpoint for it, does application enter there?

Comment: Yes. Also just a side not anything between ^{ ... }]; is considered the code block in apple documents.